# Array null not validating in javascript

Tags: javascript

In my javascript i am trying to check an array if empty.If there is no item in `<li>` then array will be empty and this should throw error but it is not working. Here is my code

```
 var phrases = [];
        $('#listDiv #hiddenItemList').each(function () {
            var phrase = '';
            $(this).find('li').each(function () {
                var current = $(this);
                phrase += $(this).text() + ";";
            });
            phrases.push(phrase);
        });

        if (phrases === undefined || phrases.length == 0 )
        {
            $.alert("Please select rate type, high rate and low rate", {
                title: "Rates Info",
                type: "danger"
            });
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: just try `if(!phrases||!phrases.length)`

Comment: There should only be one item that matches `#listDiv #hiddenItemList` as ID's must be unique so your each function should only execute 1x (kind of necessary) . Also `phrases === undefined` will always be false as you define `phrases = []`. Since you always add `phrase` to `phrases` even if empty you will always have a count, even if you don't have any `li`'s.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check that you're not just pushing an empty string into the array. This will make the array phrases have length and not be undefined but won't be what you're looking for.

```
    var phrases = [];
            $('#listDiv #hiddenItemList').each(function () {
                var phrase = '';
                $(this).find('li').each(function () {
                    var current = $(this);
                    phrase += $(this).text() + ";";
                });
                if ( phrase != '' ) {
                  phrases.push(phrase);
                }
            });

            if (phrases === undefined || phrases.length == 0 )
            {
                $.alert("Please select rate type, high rate and low rate", {
                    title: "Rates Info",
                    type: "danger"
                });
                return false;
            }
```